# grep exclude multiple columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, negate

I have several tables with multiple columns of numeric data. The number of columns can vary. Each table has 3 columns (Player, Team, Pos) that do not have numeric data. I have come up with the following to convert every column except the 3 above to numeric but I am getting stuck on an error I can not explain.

Here is the function

```
qb2 <- qb %>% mutate_at(grep("^(`?!`Player|`?!`Team|`?!`Pos).*$",
    colnames(.)),funs(as.numeric))
```

When run this way, I get NA in Player, Team & Position
Trouble shooting I can get it to partially work like this

```
qb2 <- qb %>% mutate_at(grep("^(`?!`Player|Team|`?!`Pos).*$", 
    colnames(.)),funs(as.numeric))
```

Player and Pos show correctly, but of course Team is still `NA`
I am not sure why removing `?!` from Team works partially.

Let me know what I am missing that is causing the grep/exclude to fail.

Sample data

```
structure(list(Player = c("Matt Schaub", "Jimmy Garoppolo", "Tom Savage", 
"Dan Orlovsky", "Cardale Jones", "Ryan Griffin", "Sean Mannion", 
"Luke McCown", "Scott Tolzien", "Dak Prescott", "Brandon Allen", 
"Garrett Grayson", "AJ McCarron", "Joe Callahan", "Matt Moore", 
"Matt Barkley", "Blake Bortles", "Stephen Morris", "Sean Renfree", 
"Mark Sanchez", "Jameill Showers", "Thad Lewis", "Jameis Winston", 
"Kellen Clemens", "Chad Henne", "Derek Anderson", "Bryce Petty", 
"Teddy Bridgewater", "Ryan Mallett", "EJ Manuel", "Nate Sudfeld", 
"Joe Webb", "Carson Wentz", "Trevor Siemian", "Mike Glennon", 
"Josh Johnson", "Joe Licata", "Brian Hoyer", "Geno Smith", "Joel Stave", 
"Ryan Nassib", "Paxton Lynch", "Ryan Fitzpatrick", "Jake Rudock", 
"Connor Cook", "Robert Griffin III", "Alex Tanney", "Brandon Doughty", 
"Philip Rivers", "Blaine Gabbert", "Case Keenum", "Matthew Stafford", 
"Matt Cassel", "Landry Jones", "Marquise Williams", "Colt McCoy", 
"Shaun Hill", "Aaron Murray", "Dustin Vaughan", "Tyler Bray", 
"Mike Bercovici", "Marcus Mariota", "Derek Carr", "Drew Stanton", 
"Matt McGloin", "Kirk Cousins", "Jared Goff", "Carson Palmer", 
"Drew Brees", "Nick Foles", "Cam Newton", "Alex Smith", "Russell Wilson", 
"Jake Heaps", "Andy Dalton", "Austin Davis", "David Fales", "Keith Wenning", 
"Brock Osweiler", "Bruce Gradkowski", "Zach Mettenberger", "Kevin Hogan", 
"Jeff Driskel", "Jay Cutler", "Connor Shaw", "Jake Coker", "Zac Dysert", 
"Chase Daniel", "Cody Kessler", "Logan Thomas", "Ryan Tannehill", 
"McLeod Bethel-Thompson", "Jerrod Johnson", "Tyrod Taylor", "Josh McCown", 
"Sam Bradford", "Matt Ryan", "Matt Simms"), Team = c("ATL", "NE", 
"HOU", "DET", "BUF", "TB", "LA", "NO", "IND", "DAL", "JAX", "NO", 
"CIN", "GB", "MIA", "ARI", "JAX", "IND", "ATL", "DEN", "DAL", 
"SF", "TB", "SD", "JAX", "CAR", "NYJ", "MIN", "BAL", "BUF", "WAS", 
"CAR", "PHI", "DEN", "TB", "BAL", "CIN", "CHI", "NYJ", "MIN", 
"NYG", "DEN", "NYJ", "DET", "OAK", "CLE", "TEN", "MIA", "SD", 
"SF", "LA", "DET", "TEN", "PIT", "GB", "WAS", "MIN", "KC", "PIT", 
"KC", "SD", "TEN", "OAK", "ARI", "OAK", "WAS", "LA", "ARI", "NO", 
"KC", "CAR", "KC", "SEA", "SEA", "CIN", "CLE", "CHI", "CIN", 
"HOU", "PIT", "SD", "KC", "SF", "CHI", "CHI", "ARI", "MIA", "PHI", 
"CLE", "NYG", "MIA", "PHI", "BAL", "BUF", "CLE", "PHI", "ATL", 
"ATL"), Pos = c("QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", "QB", 
"QB", "QB"), `
Comp` = c("10", "11", "14", "16", "11", "13", 
"18", "18", "12", "10", "10", "10", "11", "16", "10", "8", "6", 
"5", "5", "10", "8", "12", "7", "8", "8", "7", "7", "6", "11", 
"10", "10", "9", "12", "7", "7", "8", "3", "7", "8", "8", "7", 
"6", "3", "8", "7", "4", "6", "7", "2", "4", "6", "4", "3", "6", 
"6", "7", "6", "3", "6", "3", "3", "5", "3", "2", "5", "5", "4", 
"3", "1", "4", "5", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "3", 
"2", "2", "4", "3", "2", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "0", "0"), `
Att` = c("15", "18", "24", "25", 
"21", "23", "25", "27", "23", "12", "19", "16", "16", "23", "14", 
"24", "7", "9", "9", "13", "16", "21", "9", "15", "9", "14", 
"14", "7", "15", "18", "15", "16", "24", "12", "14", "11", "7", 
"10", "14", "13", "15", "7", "4", "11", "11", "8", "10", "9", 
"3", "10", "7", "6", "5", "12", "14", "11", "7", "5", "11", "9", 
"6", "5", "7", "6", "11", "5", "9", "5", "1", "8", "6", "4", 
"6", "10", "5", "9", "8", "8", "7", "3", "8", "6", "12", "4", 
"4", "5", "2", "10", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", 
"4", "3"), `
Pct` = c("66.7", "61.1", "58.3", "64.0", "52.4", 
"56.5", "72.0", "66.7", "52.2", "83.3", "52.6", "62.5", "68.8", 
"69.6", "71.4", "33.3", "85.7", "55.6", "55.6", "76.9", "50.0", 
"57.1", "77.8", "53.3", "88.9", "50.0", "50.0", "85.7", "73.3", 
"55.6", "66.7", "56.3", "50.0", "58.3", "50.0", "72.7", "42.9", 
"70.0", "57.1", "61.5", "46.7", "85.7", "75.0", "72.7", "63.6", 
"50.0", "60.0", "77.8", "66.7", "40.0", "85.7", "66.7", "60.0", 
"50.0", "42.9", "63.6", "85.7", "60.0", "54.5", "33.3", "50.0", 
"100.0", "42.9", "33.3", "45.5", "100.0", "44.4", "60.0", "100.0", 
"50.0", "83.3", "75.0", "50.0", "30.0", "80.0", "44.4", "50.0", 
"37.5", "57.1", "100.0", "25.0", "33.3", "33.3", "75.0", "50.0", 
"40.0", "50.0", "40.0", "100.0", "66.7", "50.0", "100.0", "50.0", 
"66.7", "25.0", "100.0", "0.0", "0.0"), `
Att/G` = c("15.0", 
"18.0", "24.0", "25.0", "21.0", "23.0", "25.0", "27.0", "23.0", 
"12.0", "19.0", "16.0", "16.0", "23.0", "14.0", "24.0", "7.0", 
"9.0", "9.0", "13.0", "16.0", "21.0", "9.0", "15.0", "9.0", "14.0", 
"14.0", "7.0", "15.0", "18.0", "15.0", "16.0", "24.0", "12.0", 
"14.0", "11.0", "7.0", "10.0", "14.0", "13.0", "15.0", "7.0", 
"4.0", "11.0", "11.0", "8.0", "10.0", "9.0", "3.0", "10.0", "7.0", 
"6.0", "5.0", "12.0", "14.0", "11.0", "7.0", "5.0", "11.0", "9.0", 
"6.0", "5.0", "7.0", "6.0", "11.0", "5.0", "9.0", "5.0", "1.0", 
"8.0", "6.0", "4.0", "6.0", "10.0", "5.0", "9.0", "8.0", "8.0", 
"7.0", "3.0", "8.0", "6.0", "12.0", "4.0", "4.0", "5.0", "2.0", 
"10.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "1.0", 
"4.0", "3.0"), `
Yds` = c("179", "168", "168", "164", "162", 
"148", "147", "143", "140", "139", "138", "133", "125", "124", 
"122", "121", "105", "104", "101", "99", "99", "97", "97", "96", 
"94", "93", "93", "92", "91", "91", "89", "89", "89", "88", "83", 
"83", "82", "81", "79", "76", "75", "74", "72", "72", "71", "67", 
"67", "66", "64", "63", "58", "58", "55", "55", "55", "53", "52", 
"52", "50", "48", "46", "45", "44", "42", "41", "39", "38", "38", 
"37", "37", "36", "36", "34", "33", "32", "32", "30", "28", "27", 
"22", "22", "21", "20", "18", "17", "16", "16", "15", "15", "12", 
"8", "7", "7", "7", "5", "3", "0", "0"), `
Avg` = c("11.9", "9.3", 
"7.0", "6.6", "7.7", "6.4", "5.9", "5.3", "6.1", "11.6", "7.3", 
"8.3", "7.8", "5.4", "8.7", "5.0", "15.0", "11.6", "11.2", "7.6", 
"6.2", "4.6", "10.8", "6.4", "10.4", "6.6", "6.6", "13.1", "6.1", 
"5.1", "5.9", "5.6", "3.7", "7.3", "5.9", "7.5", "11.7", "8.1", 
"5.6", "5.8", "5.0", "10.6", "18.0", "6.5", "6.5", "8.4", "6.7", 
"7.3", "21.3", "6.3", "8.3", "9.7", "11.0", "4.6", "3.9", "4.8", 
"7.4", "10.4", "4.5", "5.3", "7.7", "9.0", "6.3", "7.0", "3.7", 
"7.8", "4.2", "7.6", "37.0", "4.6", "6.0", "9.0", "5.7", "3.3", 
"6.4", "3.6", "3.8", "3.5", "3.9", "7.3", "2.8", "3.5", "1.7", 
"4.5", "4.3", "3.2", "8.0", "1.5", "7.5", "4.0", "2.0", "7.0", 
"3.5", "2.3", "1.3", "3.0", "0.0", "0.0"), `
Yds/G` = c("179.0", 
"168.0", "168.0", "164.0", "162.0", "148.0", "147.0", "143.0", 
"140.0", "139.0", "138.0", "133.0", "125.0", "124.0", "122.0", 
"121.0", "105.0", "104.0", "101.0", "99.0", "99.0", "97.0", "97.0", 
"96.0", "94.0", "93.0", "93.0", "92.0", "91.0", "91.0", "89.0", 
"89.0", "89.0", "88.0", "83.0", "83.0", "82.0", "81.0", "79.0", 
"76.0", "75.0", "74.0", "72.0", "72.0", "71.0", "67.0", "67.0", 
"66.0", "64.0", "63.0", "58.0", "58.0", "55.0", "55.0", "55.0", 
"53.0", "52.0", "52.0", "50.0", "48.0", "46.0", "45.0", "44.0", 
"42.0", "41.0", "39.0", "38.0", "38.0", "37.0", "37.0", "36.0", 
"36.0", "34.0", "33.0", "32.0", "32.0", "30.0", "28.0", "27.0", 
"22.0", "22.0", "21.0", "20.0", "18.0", "17.0", "16.0", "16.0", 
"15.0", "15.0", "12.0", "8.0", "7.0", "7.0", "7.0", "5.0", "3.0", 
"0.0", "0.0"), `
TD` = c("0", "0", "2", "1", "1", "0", "3", "1", 
"1", "2", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
    `
Int` = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
    "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
    "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), `
1st` = c("5", "7", "10", "10", "6", 
    "6", "10", "7", "5", "7", "4", "6", "5", "9", "5", "7", "4", 
    "3", "3", "5", "2", "6", "5", "4", "5", "5", "5", "4", "5", 
    "4", "5", "3", "2", "3", "4", "5", "3", "2", "4", "6", "4", 
    "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", 
    "1", "4", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `
1st%` = c("33.3", 
    "38.9", "41.7", "40.0", "28.6", "26.1", "40.0", "25.9", "21.7", 
    "58.3", "21.1", "37.5", "31.3", "39.1", "35.7", "29.2", "57.1", 
    "33.3", "33.3", "38.5", "12.5", "28.6", "55.6", "26.7", "55.6", 
    "35.7", "35.7", "57.1", "33.3", "22.2", "33.3", "18.8", "8.3", 
    "25.0", "28.6", "45.5", "42.9", "20.0", "28.6", "46.2", "26.7", 
    "57.1", "50.0", "27.3", "18.2", "25.0", "20.0", "33.3", "66.7", 
    "20.0", "28.6", "50.0", "40.0", "8.3", "28.6", "9.1", "57.1", 
    "40.0", "18.2", "22.2", "33.3", "20.0", "28.6", "33.3", "18.2", 
    "40.0", "33.3", "40.0", "100.0", "25.0", "50.0", "50.0", 
    "50.0", "30.0", "40.0", "22.2", "12.5", "12.5", "14.3", "33.3", 
    "12.5", "16.7", "0.0", "25.0", "25.0", "20.0", "50.0", "0.0", 
    "50.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
    "0.0", "0.0"), `
Lng` = c("68", "56", "24", "28T", "40", 
    "25", "16", "20", "42T", "32T", "27", "28", "40", "18", "51T", 
    "30", "45", "57T", "48", "32T", "47", "14", "26T", "17", 
    "36", "23", "21", "49T", "19T", "26", "28", "35", "19", "22", 
    "30", "29", "47", "28", "18", "22", "24", "22", "43", "27T", 
    "32", "49", "23", "24", "44T", "43T", "20", "30", "24", "29T", 
    "16", "19", "18", "25", "16", "23", "19", "31", "22", "32", 
    "19T", "11", "14", "30", "37", "19", "10", "20", "12", "13", 
    "9", "19", "13", "14", "12", "9", "14", "15", "11", "12", 
    "13", "13", "16T", "9", "10T", "7", "7", "7", "7", "5", "5", 
    "3", "--", "--"), `
20+` = c("2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "2", 
    "0", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "0", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "1", "1", "2", "2", "0", "1", 
    "2", "1", "0", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "0", "1", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", 
    "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `
40+` = c("2", 
    "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", 
    "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), `
Sck` = c("0", "2", "2", "0", "1", "1", "0", "2", 
    "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "3", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
    "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0", "1", "3", "2", 
    "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "3", "0", "0", "4", "3", "1", "0", 
    "0", "0", "2", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
    "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", 
    "2", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "4", "3", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"), `
Rate` = c("107.4", "91.9", 
    "107.6", "79.4", "93.8", "39.8", "109.5", "76.6", "85.4", 
    "154.5", "54.3", "62.8", "112.8", "97.0", "92.0", "33.5", 
    "118.8", "133.6", "95.1", "91.5", "69.5", "68.9", "148.6", 
    "73.2", "110.2", "95.2", "71.4", "158.3", "82.9", "88.0", 
    "104.6", "72.1", "41.8", "81.2", "38.7", "94.1", "47.0", 
    "54.6", "97.0", "45.7", "22.2", "110.7", "116.7", "120.3", 
    "82.0", "39.1", "80.0", "97.2", "149.3", "95.0", "101.2", 
    "97.9", "97.9", "90.6", "24.4", "75.2", "97.6", "95.4", "66.5", 
    "52.1", "36.1", "104.2", "64.0", "19.4", "95.1", "99.2", 
    "17.1", "83.8", "118.8", "63.0", "91.7", "102.1", "27.8", 
    "40.8", "93.3", "53.9", "59.4", "8.3", "65.8", "97.2", "0.0", 
    "4.9", "42.4", "83.3", "61.5", "48.8", "116.7", "47.9", "137.5", 
    "74.3", "56.2", "95.8", "58.3", "70.1", "39.6", "79.2", "39.6", 
    "39.6")), .Names = c("Player", "Team", "Pos", "\nComp", "\nAtt", 
"\nPct", "\nAtt/G", "\nYds", "\nAvg", "\nYds/G", "\nTD", "\nInt", 
"\n1st", "\n1st%", "\nLng", "\n20+", "\n40+", "\nSck", "\nRate"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 98L))
```

Comment: please provide us with the data or analogous data

Comment: `qb2[] <- lapply(qb2, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: You might be interested in `type_convert` from package readr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NA's are coming from the "--" and "T":

```
qb[,-c(1:3)] <- apply(qb[,-c(1:3)], 2, as.numeric)
```

The one column has several values that are not numeric:

```
 Lng = c("68", "56", "24", "28T", "40", 
"25", "16", "20", "42T", "32T", "27", "28", "40", "18", "51T", 
"30", "45", "57T", "48", "32T", "47", "14", "26T", "17", 
"36", "23", "21", "49T", "19T", "26", "28", "35", "19", "22", 
"30", "29", "47", "28", "18", "22", "24", "22", "43", "27T", 
"32", "49", "23", "24", "44T", "43T", "20", "30", "24", "29T", 
"16", "19", "18", "25", "16", "23", "19", "31", "22", "32", 
"19T", "11", "14", "30", "37", "19", "10", "20", "12", "13", 
"9", "19", "13", "14", "12", "9", "14", "15", "11", "12", 
"13", "13", "16T", "9", "10T", "7", "7", "7", "7", "5", "5", 
"3", "--", "--"),
```

Ultimately you want this:

```
qb[,-c(1:3)] <- apply(qb[,-c(1:3)], 2, function(x) gsub("--|T", "", x))

qb[,-c(1:3)] <- apply(qb[,-c(1:3)], 2, as.numeric)
```

Comment: I got the same result. Player Team and Pos change to NA. There was an error about an extra ',' but after correcting got the following

    inline`Warning messages:
    1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
    2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
    3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
    4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion`,

Comment: What happens when you only do the first step above?

Comment: Nothing actually happens. the qb table stays exactly the same

Comment: Will they non numeric columns always be at the beginning if so its quite easy

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want every column except Player, Pos and Team to be numeric so I can run calculations on the numbers.

Comment: Yes always at the beginning

Comment: Hit the nail right on the head! I don't mind the NA in "Lng" Column, it was the NA in the Team column that was tripping me up. 

Your is exactly what I needed and accounts for future issues where numeric columns may have no numeric data.

Comment: Actually you might prefer: `qb[,-c(1:3)] <- apply(qb[,-c(1:3)], 2, function(x) gsub("--|T", 0, x))` That leaves you with no NA values and 0's instead, and is probably what I should have written in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `one_of` function from `dplyr`, `one_of` accepts a character vector for the column names that can be excluded from the mutation by negating the selection with a `-` in front:

```
df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("Player", "Team", "Pos"))), funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
      lapply(class)

# $Player
# [1] "character"

# $Team
# [1] "character"

# $Pos
# [1] "character"

# $`\nComp`
# [1] "numeric"

# $`\nAtt`
# [1] "numeric"

# other numeric columns here...

df %>% 
       mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("Player", "Team", "Pos"))), funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
       head()

#           Player Team Pos \nComp \nAtt \nPct \nAtt/G \nYds \nAvg \nYds/G
#1     Matt Schaub  ATL  QB     10    15  66.7      15   179  11.9     179
#2 Jimmy Garoppolo   NE  QB     11    18  61.1      18   168   9.3     168
#3      Tom Savage  HOU  QB     14    24  58.3      24   168   7.0     168
#4    Dan Orlovsky  DET  QB     16    25  64.0      25   164   6.6     164
#5   Cardale Jones  BUF  QB     11    21  52.4      21   162   7.7     162
#6    Ryan Griffin   TB  QB     13    23  56.5      23   148   6.4     148
#  \nTD \nInt \n1st \n1st% \nLng \n20+ \n40+ \nSck \nRate
#1    0     0     5   33.3    68     2     2     0  107.4
#2    0     0     7   38.9    56     2     1     2   91.9
#3    2     0    10   41.7    24     4     0     2  107.6
#4    1     1    10   40.0    NA     3     0     0   79.4
#5    1     0     6   28.6    40     3     1     1   93.8
#6    0     2     6   26.1    25     2     0     1   39.8
```

A smaller example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("x", "y", "z"), b = c("m", "n", "l"), c = 1:3, d = 2:4)
df
#   a b c d
# 1 x m 1 2
# 2 y n 2 3
# 3 z l 3 4

df %>% mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("a", "b"))), funs(.*2))
#   a b c d
# 1 x m 2 4
# 2 y n 4 6
# 3 z l 6 8
```

Comment: that doesn't work on the data.frame the OP provided...besdies, the "smaller example" has two columns that are factors 2 that are integers. His original data are a mix of numbers and strings all of which are characters.

Comment: I posted the comment before an edit was made on answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do the conversion in the long format, that I go again to the wide format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dx)
dcast(melt(dx,id=c("Player","Team", "Pos"))[,value:=as.numeric(value)],
      Player+Team+Pos~variable)
```

where `dx` is one of your data.frame. This can be easily generlised to many data.frames but it depends if you want to have the final result as a single data.table that aggregates all the data.frames or not.